# Extract original image (including metadata) from email

Tags: gmail, images

I've received an email with an embedded image I would like to pull the EXIF data from.

If this were an attachment it wouldn't be a big deal, but the image was embedded, and I can only view the image, or save it (which saves the image as a new file).

From gmail, is there any way to extract the original embedded image? Or do I need to forward it somewhere, or download something to scrape it off the .eml file?

Thanks!